# Itemize a name list randomly several times throught the document

Tags: lists, random, probsoln

I have a list of names, say:

```
 \newcommand{\names}{Fred, Barry, Joe, Jack, Zach}
```

and I just want to display the list in a randomized order a few times through my document.

Something like:

`Barry, Zach, Joe, Jack, Fred`
at the beginning  and

`Joe, Zach, Barry, Fred, Jack`
near the middle of the document.

The closest simple solution I found was to use the package

```
\usepackage{probsoln}
\PSNrandseed{\time}
```

and in the document call:

```
\doforrandN{5}{\who}{\studentsnames}{ 
    \who
}
```

But the problem is that the seed for randomization is created only once per compilation. Thus calling the randomized list twice in my document will give me two identical lists.
Any other simple way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use L3 and its `\seq_shuffle:N` function. The following wraps it in some convenient macros:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \setNameList { m m }
  {
    \seq_clear_new:c { l__andrew_namelist_#1_seq }
    \seq_set_from_clist:cn { l__andrew_namelist_#1_seq } {#2}
  }
\msg_new:nnn { andrew } { unknown-list } { Unknown~ list~ #1 }
\NewDocumentCommand \useNameListShuffled { m O{,~} }
  {
    \seq_if_exist:cTF { l__andrew_namelist_#1_seq }
      {
        \group_begin:
          \seq_shuffle:c { l__andrew_namelist_#1_seq }
          \seq_use:cn { l__andrew_namelist_#1_seq } {#2}
        \group_end:
      }
      { \msg_error:nnn { andrew } { unknown-list } {#1} }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\setNameList{names}{Fred, Barry, Joe, Jack, Zach}


\begin{document}
\useNameListShuffled{names}

\useNameListShuffled{names}[ and ]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very happy to have this working although I have not much idea of what is going on :)

Comment: We store the list you gave in an ordered data structure (a sequence), the name of the sequence is built on the fly depending on your input (that's what the `c`-argument type is used for, it builds a control sequence name from the input using `\csname`). When you then want to randomly access it we shuffle that list (locally, so afterwards the original order is restored) and input it in its shuffled state. Do you need more explanations?

Comment: So far I'm good, thanks for your explanations @skillmon.

Answer (score 2):

This is <strike>(potentially)</strike> horrible code, but it will work (possibly by accident more than design).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn


\clist_new:N \l__andrew_students
\clist_set:Nn \l__andrew_students{Zack, Barry, Fred, Jack, Joe}
\cs_new:Nn \print_students: {\clist_use:Nnnn \l__andrew_students {~and~} {,~} {,~ and~} }

\cs_new:Nn \randomise_students: {

        \clist_sort:Nn \l__andrew_students {
                \fp_compare:nNnTF {rand()} > {0.5}
                { \sort_return_swapped: }
                { \sort_return_same: }
        }

}

\cs_new_eq:NN \randomisestudents\randomise_students:
\cs_new_eq:NN \printstudents\print_students:

\ExplSyntaxOff

\printstudents
\randomisestudents

\printstudents

\randomisestudents
\printstudents

\end{document}
```

To set the initial list may need another command, depending on how many times you need to change the list.

EDIT: I have a bit more time now, so a small amount of explanation.

I chose `clist` rather than `seq` (like @Skillmon's answer), but they behave (at least from a user's perspective) much the same (on the version I tested against). I did look through `interface3.pdf` for "shuffle", but didn't find it. I suspect that is due to the age of the install - it's the one that my (not exactly new) Linux package manager supplies (I think it's TeX Live 2018, but am not at that computer right now). I can see (on a more modern TeX Live) that `seq` has shuffle, and `clist` doesn't, though.

I have edited the style a bit, but I suspect it is still not fantastic.

Explanation of code:

- `\clist_set:Nn` sets the named variable to the provided comma-separated list
- the sort algorithm decides to swap two members of the list depending on if a random floating-point number (from 0 to 1) is bigger than .5 (rather than inherent features of the list)
- the `\clist_use:Nnnn` will print commas between items (except for the last two, which will be a comma and the word "and")
- This version will keep the order, unless `\randomisestudents` is called, which is slightly different from the other answer. This can be changed, by putting a call to `\randomise_students:` in the `\print_students:` method (either before or after the `clist_use`)

As @DavidCarlisle mentions, the use of `rand > 0.5` in a sort may lead to the sort never terminating, if the sort algorithm assumes `a>b` and `b>c` then `a>c`. As a result, I would not use this method or code for anything but a one-off project, where I can stop the run and restart if it looks like it is non-terminating.

Because it worked during testing, I didn't think too much about potential pitfalls.

Comment: this seems to work but many sorting algorithms would fail or even fail to terminate with a comparison operator rand()} > {0.5} as they often assume that at a>b and b>c implies a>c

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I guess since `\clist_sort:Nn` uses a stable Quicksort (iirc without some cunning pivoting) this works out, as everything has to be compared only once to the same pivot, and never against anything that was on the other side of that pivot.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, you are absolutely correct, and I hadn't considered the pitfalls of this approach. I did test it (non-exhaustively), though, and when it worked, I stopped and called it good (or at least OK).

Comment: Thanks a lot  for your answer. I have tried and chosen Skillmon solution because it works and you advise against using your solution regularly.